# How to fixed Undefined index: ORIG_PATH_INFO and Undefined index: PATH_INFO on localhost

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I have some problem when I tried to run my website on localhost. After I configure all of the config and I run the site I got this error.

```
Notice: Undefined index: ORIG_PATH_INFO 
Notice: Undefined index: PATH_INFO
```

I used this code in my function :

```
$path = str_replace(".php","",$_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO']); 
if($path == ""){$path = str_replace(".php","",$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']); }
```

My questions is why I got that error and how to fixed this error ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef

Comment: superglobal variable `$_SERVER` does not have to have everything setted up... check before use if its set or not like `if(isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'])){ /* use */ }`